# How to launch Chrome in mobile emulator Landscape mode using C# Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium

I was able to launch a web page using Chrome browser in mobile portrait emulator mode using this C# code:

```
     ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

     options.AddArguments("disable-infobars");

    options.AddArguments("start-maximized");

    options.EnableMobileEmulation("Galaxy S5");

     IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

     driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.udemy.com");
```

I want to launch the same page in mobile landscape emulator mode, but having trouble finding a solution.  There are solution using Java, Ruby and Python but I need solution for C#.

I only want to launch Chrome browser using .NET C# Selenium in Landscape emulator mode. Could you please help?

Comment: I don't know C#, but this might help: https://www.browserstack.com/automate/c-sharp.  But your question is off-topic.  Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers

Answer (score 0):

In Appium Studio, it goes like this

```
client.deviceAction("Portrait");
```

For a detailed explanation you can check out [their](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/DeviceAction) documentation.